# Codeigniter - Displaying page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a problem displaying my index.php in codeigniter. Can someone help me with this?

Here's my index.php:

```
<form id="myForm" action="<?php echo baseurl('controller/CreateUser'); ?>" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
    <button id="sub">Save</button>
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

And here's my controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->view( 'layouts/header', [ 'title' => 'Never Stop Learning!' ] );
    $this->load->view( 'NeverStopLearning/index');
    $this->load->view( 'layouts/footer' );
}

public function CreateUser(){
    $data = array(
        "name" => $this->input->post("name"),
        "username" => $this->input->post("username"),
        "password" => $this->input->post("password")
    );

    if($this->model->Insert('table_users', $data)){
        echo "Successfully Inserted";
    }else{
        echo "Insertion Failed";
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem you're having? What happens if you visit the controllers URL. Also, what kind of webserver are you using, php version. Also post your routeconfig

Comment: it just display white screen sir, no error my PHP Version is 5.6.14

Comment: Is the index.php file in the folder `application/views/NeverStopLearning`?  Also, if you turn error reporting on, what error is shown?

Comment: Either what you're loading is in fact empty, or you're not reporting errors. Check your PHP.ini file in your apache bin directory, and set it to E_ALL